# How to restrict file types with HTML input file type?

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc

How do I restrict file types with the HTML input file type?

I have this

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23" accept="Calendar/ics"/>
```

I am trying to restrict the type to only the iCalendar format type.

I also want to check it on the server side. How do I do this in [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't restrict the file extension like you can in a standard file browser dialog.  You can, however, check the extension once the user selects a file.

You can add this event handler.

```
filebox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "fileSelectedChanged(this);");
```

and this JavaScript function

```
function fileSelectedChanged(obj) {
    var filePath = obj.value;

    var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
    if(ext != 'csv') {
        alert('Only files with the file extension CSV are allowed');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }
}
```

You should also check it on the server, using:

```
filebox.PostedFile.FileName
```

and:

```
filebox.PostedFile.ContentType
```

Comment: do you mean when they upload the file to the server or the when they click on the file in the "choose file dialog"?

Comment: This is done in JavaScript when the user selects a new file (I included a function for you)

Comment: Remember to accept this answer if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: lol...gabriel. he's got 2000 rep and 88% accept ratio... i think he knows.

Answer (score 3):

text/calendar is the right mime type

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23" accept="text/calendar" />
```

Comment: Current browsers generally ignore the ACCEPT attribute

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the accept attribute. Still needs to be validated server-side ofc, but can help reduce resource usage on the server as files that don't hit the server don't need to be checked.

Comment: as Gabriel said this attribute is generally ingored by major browsers so you have to use javascript for "pre-validation".

Answer (score 1):

instaed of accept you should use contetypes attribute notice that there is single "t"
in contentypes

and in server code check like this

HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];

if(!file.ContentType.startsWith("text/calendar"))
{
    //Error
}

hope this will sove your problem Mark my answer if it will.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify what kind of files the user can choose.  You can use Javascript to prevent the user from submitting the form, but that is not good enough.  Javascript can be easily disabled within the browser.  You need logic on the server-side that evaluates the content-type of the upload (even just checking the file extension is really not good enough)...

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files(0);

if(file.ContentType != "text/calendar")
{
    //Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer something like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) which lets you do this, and also provides a fancy progress bar... I don't know if that's a bit too "heavy weight" for you though.